# UIBarButtonItem with Image is only partially clickable

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I've googled and SO'd for this every few days for weeks and never found even a similar question, yet I'm sure other's must suffer it. So here goes:
In a nutshell: I'm creating a UIBarButtonItem in the toolbar of a UINavigationController in an iPhone app which has an image in it, and when I click that button I have to click on a very specific part for it to work.

I have several such buttons and each one is sensitive in different parts. It almost seems to depend on where the transparency is in the image - but I'm not sure.

Here's the code that creates such a button:

```
_addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"50-plus"]
                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                            target:self
                                            action:@selector(addButtonPressed:)];
```

The code that loads it into the toolbar is a bit conditional, but basically it puts this button in an NSMutableArray and calls `[controller setToolbarItems:items animated:YES]` where `controller` is a UITableViewControler housed in a UINavigationController.

Some other details in case it helps:

- I'm only trying this in XCode 4.3 with the iPhone 5.1 Simulator
- The image is a white icon from the glyphish icon set (glyphish.com)
- The "click area" of the button is small but consistent, somewhere in the bottom left quadrant for this + button but different for buttons with other images
- The button does work, completely as expected, but only if I click in the very specific area

Comment: +1, glad you asked. I've seen similar problems with my UIBarButtonItems, but it seemed more of a top/bottom thing.